# Custom DataType in drag'n'drop between JavaFX & HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I would like to mix JavaFX and HTML5/JS inside a JavaFX-based application. HTML5/JS components would be integrated using the JavaFX WebView and there will be one instance of WebView per HTML5/JS component.

Considering the class *Person{String:firstname, String:lastname}*, I'm investigating the feasibility of drag'n'drop between JavaFX and HTML5. My goal is to be able to drop my model objects as the following MIME types:

1. "*text/plain*" - This is the standard MIME type for text. My data would be something like "*Mr jerry seinfeld*"
2. "*application/x-pigelvy-person*" - This would be my own MIME type and it would let me detect that the Drag'n'Drop operation is actually about a Person object. The data would then by the dragged Person converted to JSON such as *{"firstname":"jerry","lastname":"seinfeld"}*.

You can check my sources at https://github.com/pigelvy/dnd_jfx-js.

Starting the drag operation a JavaFX ListView and putting the Person object in the ClipboardContent as "*text/plain*" and "*application/x-pigelvy-person*", I was only able to get data for "*text/plain*" (though the JS object DragEvent.dataTransfer). I have the same result no matter which browser I use (WebView in app or Firefox/Chrome outside my app)

I just read the [HTML5 D'n'D specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/dnd.html) and based on section [7.8.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/dnd.html#when-the-drag-and-drop-operation-starts-or-ends-in-another-document) and [7.8.4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/dnd.html#when-the-drag-and-drop-operation-starts-or-ends-in-another-application) I understand that the D'n'D should correctly even when it starts/ends from/in another application/document.

I just noticed some weird things:

1. Loading my HTML page on 2 Firefox tabs or 2 Opera tabs, I have access to my custom MIME type along with "*text/plain*".
2. Loading my HTML page on 2 JavaFX WebViews within the same JavaFX application, I do have access to my custom MIME type, but only to "*text/plain*".

Why isn't my custom data type available? Are there any restrictions I don't know about?

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I am having a very similar situation, I can not dnd objects with custom mime types between the browser and JavaFx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag'n Drop is not in the HTML5 specification. It's a work in progress for HTML5.1

The fact is that, today, for whatever reason, it's not possible to D'n'D exotic MIME types between different browsers and JavaFX WebViews.